# Couldnot execute the dynamically linked program

Tags: c, cmd

Hi I tried doing static library and a shared library with the gnu compiler, here is following code

following is the code for the library
    calc_mean.c

```
double mean(double a, double b){
return (a+b)/2;
}
```

following is my header file calc_mean.h

```
double mean(double,double);
```

Now i started creating static library using following commands

first , calc_mean.c is turned into an object file

```
gcc -c calc_mean.c -o calc_mean.o
```

second ,the archiver (ar) is invoked to produce a static
library (named libmean.a) out of the object file calc_mean.o

```
ar rcs libmean.a calc_mean.o
```

third, created shared library before that using -fPIC option
created an independant code which is necessary for shared library

```
gcc -c -fPIC calc_mean.c -o calc_mean.o
```

now the shared library is created using following command line

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmean.so.1 -o libmean.so.1.0.1 calc_mean.o
```

finally my main.c file that uses the library is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calc_mean.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

double v1,v2,m;
v1 = 5.2;
v2 = 7.9;
m=mean(v1,v2);
printf("The mean of %3.2f and %3.2f is %3.2f\n",v1,v2,m);
return 0;
 }
```

finally I linked the program against static library that generated a statically_linked.exe

```
gcc -static main.c -L. -lmean -o statically_linked
```

when dynamically linked, it generated a dynamically_linked.exe with the following command

```
gcc main.c -o dynamically_linked -L. -lmean
```

Now when i use the command to execute the dynamically linked program using the following command, Iam getting an error message saying LD_LIBRARY is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.D:\c\project3./dynamically_linked
```

how can I execute the dynamically linked program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line suggests that you do all this on windows. But you seem to have followed a step by step guide for linux or another *nix platform.

On windows, a dynamically linked library is in `.dll` format (not `.so`) and there's no versioning convention, so the command to create the shared library should look a little different.

Instead of:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmean.so.1 -o libmean.so.1.0.1 calc_mean.o
```

do the following on windows:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,--out-implib,libmean.dll.a -o mean-1.dll calc_mean.o
```

This creates the library itself named `mean-1.dll` as well as an *import library* named `libmean.dll.a`. The *import library* (sometimes called `.lib` instead of `.dll.a`) on the windows platform is just a stub used during linking of your program, AFAIK MinGW doesn't need it, but other compilers could.

Linking your main program should then work with the same command:

```
gcc main.c -o dynamically_linked -L. -lmean
```

And for finding `.dll` libraries in windows, there is no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- windows just looks for them in the standard search path, including the directory of the `.exe` requiring it. IOW, you should be able to just run your program.

Comment: yeah it worked.. thankyou got it, Can i keep the calc_mean.c and calc_mean.h  in the different folder where main.c is not located and want to make libraries and link them to main.c in another folder, Will it run? I am a beginner by the way.

Comment: You can keep headers (`.h`) wherever, just pass the correct include path using a `-I` flag during compilation. Similarly, you can keep (import) libraries wherever, just pass the correct library search path using a `-L` flag during linking.

Comment: @jenny glad it worked for you. Btw, did you know you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) an answer that solved your problem? This gives the author of the answer some reputation (and also a little yourself), and, more importantly, shows later readers at a glance that the solution worked. Of course you don't need to do this :)

Comment: Oh yeah.. i didnt know it before, yes it has mutual benefit! :D